# QString как аргумент для QPainter::DrawText - когда проиходит вызов деструктора

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте. Если я в QPainter::DrawText передаю QString созданную прямо среди передаваемых аргументов как показанно ниже:

```
void func(){
   for(int i=1; i<=l;i++)
       qpainter_prt->drawText(1, 1, 1,1, Qt::AlignLeft, QString("%1").arg(i));
}
```

То:
1-вызывается ли деструктор QString сразу после вызова функции QPainter::DrawText?
2-вызывается ли деструктор после окончании func()?
3-если вызывается деструктор QString и объект уничтожается то как QPainter будет его рисовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Да, сразу после вызова drawText() вызывается деструктор стекового аргумента QString.
2. Нет, т.к. он уже разрушен. См. ответ на п.1
3. Да, будет, т.к. он использует копию объекта QString.

Comment: но как QPainter QPainter будет использовать копию если в функцию передается ссылка о чем свидетельствует & в мануале?
void QPainter::drawText ( const QPoint & position, const QString & text )

Comment: конструкция "const QString & text" с наибольшей вероятностью свидетельствует о том, что text будет или скопирован внутри метода drawText, или же будет сразу использован. Главное - гарантируется неприкосновенность объекта-аргумента text, и единственное, что требуется от такого аргумента - это существование на протяжении вызова drawText().